# Choice of reference/mid-slice during SPM slice-timing-correction

Tags: neuroimaging, spm

I'm trying to figure out the simultaneous-multi-slice (SMS) factor for my MR acquisition, to use during slice-timing correction, in SPM12.

The DICOM header obtained during conversion (with the Matlab script dicom_sort_convert_main) is a mess, and the only variable that sounds like it *could* be the SMS, is: sKSpace.ucMultiSliceMode=2.

Assuming the total number of slices is nSlices=64, is it then correct that my reference slice should be the 16th one (i.e. divide nSlices by 2 to get the mid-slice, and by SMS=2 again) ? And that it is the timing of *this* mid-slice (irrespective of what the TR was), that I should use as a reference, in the SliceTimingCorrection SPM batch?